# Why won't my user input field reset after submitting?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search for a recipe">
  <button id="submit" name="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
      // console.log("Submit button was clicked!");
      $('#query').val('');
      callAPI(getInput());
    });
```

The input field still maintains the text even after I click submit. I want it to disappear and just show the placeholder value specified in the HTML code.

Comment: `$('#query').val('');` is correct and should work. is there other error in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working properly...

Please check your JQuery Library Proper add or not.

```js
$("#submit").click( function() {
      // console.log("Submit button was clicked!");
      $('#query').val('');
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search for a recipe">
  <button id="submit" name="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have the jquery file but also I realized it was because I triggered it so that you can also submit via enter and so that required me to incorporate the function into that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS (not jQuery) method `.reset()` on form to reset all it's fields

```js
$("#submit").click( function() {
  $(this).closest('form')[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input placeholder="Enter text"/>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work perfectly.
Do you get any errors in the console?

Also, please check that its not your browser caching a old version of your code.

[image]